# NodeJS, Express: How to redirect to the oAuth origin

Tags: node.js, express

I'm doing oAuth authentication in Express with Passport.js. I want to redirect the users back to the page they came from once the oAuth is complete. How do I do that?

For example, in Rails I have this:

```
redirect_to request.env['omniauth.origin']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if referrer is present `res.redirect('back')`

Comment: damn that guy beat me by 37 seconds

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in an oAuth authentication, so the user goes through multiple pages.